# .NET Compiler -- Are there nested loop optimizations built-in?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code snippet, a traversal of a three dimensional array of singles, in terms of execution efficiency, assuming that `process1()` and `process2()` take identical lengths of time to execute:

```
float arr[mMax,nMax,oMax];

for (m = 0; m < mMax; m++)
  for (n = 0; n < nMax; n++)
    for (o = 0; o < oMax; o++)
      { process1(arr[m,n,o]); }

for (o = 0; o < oMax; o++)
  for (n = 0; n < nMax; n++)
    for (m = 0; m < mMax; m++)
      { process2(arr[m,n,o]); }
```

Now, it's known that C# organizes arrays in the .NET framework as row-major structures. Without any optimization I would assume that the first loop will execute much faster than the second one.

The question is: Does the CLR's JIT or the cs.exe/vb.exe compilers detect and optimize loops like this, perhaps reordering the nesting, or should I always be on my guard for potential performance hits, especially in terms of what might happen if I tried to parallelize the loops?

Comment: In general case you should not hope on the compiler optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of optimization you *might* expect in a C or C++ compiler.  It is actually rather current, this exact optimization was mentioned in [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-329) of a Build 2013 session.  While targeted to C/C++ programmers, a lot what is covered there is interesting to C# programmers as well.  The constraints of the memory subsystem are equally relevant.  Not actually sure if the optimization made it into VS2013, iirc there was a problem with it slowing down the native compiler too much as well.

But no, the jitter optimizer works on a very tight budget.  Spending too much time causes noticeable startup delays and execution pauses so it cannot afford this kind of analysis.  C# programmers have to do this themselves.

Comment: The video is fascinating; thanks for linking to it. I have the impression, though, that the C# compiler development group is not integrated closely enough with the C/C++ development group to assure us that those optimizations are in the pipeline. Would you agree with that?